# High traffic site. >10 million user a day. VPS or dedicated server?

Tags: iphone, ios, debian, vps

We're launching an iPhone app soon, and if everything goes well, we might reach up to tens of millions of user each day.

What server solution would you use for this? I guess a small VPS isn't enough. Is dedicated server a better choice? Is there any good hosting provider that can provide such servers?

I'm a newbie when It comes to servers, and would like some basic info about how to handle this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, you might want to look into cloud computing. Then you are not throwing out the big bucks while your app has relatively light traffic and not using the server to the full extent. Furthermore, it scales as quickly as you need, so you will not be in the position where the dedicated server is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Can I still run a linux server (apache, php etc.) on it as a regular VPS?

Comment: What does your app require? What information is passed back and forth? JSON, XML, HTML, ... ? Normal cloud computing varies from you giving them your server app and they will run it, to you having more freedom.

Comment: At 10 million users a day, I sure hope that you can afford a system engineer to tell you what is needed. And .. Off Topic.

Comment: Mostly JSON and some images. I looked at amazon cloud ec2 solutions. Would that be a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are not really going to know the apps requirements until the app is launched. It all depends on how much the app needs to communicate with the server, and how often users are using the app. Depending on those variables and even more, a VPS might be enough, or you may need a dedicated box, or several. It also depends a lot on the performance of the VPS and dedicated boxes, furthermore it depends on how much access to the system you need.

Ultimately, it seems you may not even know how well the app is going to do, so I suggest you take the cheap/efficient route of using cloud computing. That way you will limit your expenses initially when you app has a small user base. Then your performance can amp up as quickly as your app requires (of course so will the price). That is the benefit of cloud computing, you will not be losing money in the beginning until you have the user base to use your server to its limit. Furthermore, you do not have downtime, etc when/if your server is no longer enough.

Check out [Google's Cloud Computing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) to get a hint of what is possible. I personally like Google's cloud experience, but you have many more options with varying degrees of freedom that you will have to check out. [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/) of course is another possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We have already lanuched the app in one country, and have about 200,000 users. So we have some insights. But we have a small VPS that is enough for now, but won't it won't be able to handle 50 millions users... Is there any drawbacks with cloud hosting, compared to a dedicated server?

Comment: Dedicated server gives you complete access to the box. You own it essentially. Anything goes. As for cloud computing, it is closer to VPS setup or even more limited. You have all the computing/storage power you need, but you have to do so in a limited scope. You will not be able to make system changes. However if your app is mostly just using JSON/images from the filesystem or a database it should be no problem. You will may have to change some aspects of the server backend to take advantage of various cloud resources.